# Calculate the first instance of a value in axis xarray?

Tags: python, indexing, python-xarray

I have some input atmospheric model data of clouds in multi dimensions (3D): latitude , longitude and elevation.

I'm trying to calculate cloud top height from this input data; so for each grid cell or column in model,  I need to find the highest instance where this input data is greater than a threshold.

I found some relevant posts but still stuck with my issue:

Here's an example, let s say I have an Xarray such as:

```
>>> cloud = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(2,2,2),dims=list('abc'),coords=dict(c=range(2)))
>>> cloud
<xarray.DataArray (a: 2, b: 2, c: 2)>
array([[[0.6108219 , 0.04207269],
        [0.83198781, 0.84218767]],

       [[0.20666094, 0.5510897 ],
        [0.23786604, 0.82793776]]])
Coordinates:
  * c        (c) int64 0 1
Dimensions without coordinates: a, b
```

Let's now filter values using third dimension (dim c ), to get the highest index in the c axis with a value greater than a specific threshold:

```
>>> index=cloud.where(lambda x: x>0.6).idxmax(dim='c')
>>> index
<xarray.DataArray 'c' (a: 2, b: 2)>
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [nan,  1.]])
Dimensions without coordinates: a, b
```

Now I would like to find the best way (without loop) to obtain an 2D xarray(a:5, b:5) (top_cloud) containing the values (xarray cloud) associated to the  indices (xarray index).

```
top_cloud
<xarray.DataArray 'c' (a: 2, b: 2)>
array([[0.6108219, 0.84218767],
       [nan, 0.82793776]])
Dimensions without coordinates: a, b
```

Many thanks for your help !

Guillaume

Comment: Before finding the associated value, just clarifying that .idxmax will find the index of the maximum, not the maximum index corresponding to a non-null value. Is this what you want? Also, your question title doesn’t seem to me to match what you’re asking about. Could you clarify you question, maybe with a smaller 1D or very small 2D example dataset where you could manually indicate the result you’re hoping for?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just edited the text with a simple example, hope it s more clear.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

The short answer is - you should broadcast the "is cloud" condition against the elevation dim itself so you get the elevations of valid clouds, then take the max:

```py
max_cloud_elev = cloud.c.where(cloud > 0.6).max(dim="c")
cloud.sel(c=max_cloud_elev.fillna(0).astype(int)).where(max_cloud_elev.notnull())
```

#### Full example

I'll create an example that has a few more observations along `c` to make sure we have some more ambiguous cases:

```py
In [7]: cloud = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(2,2,5),dims=list('abc'),coords=dict(c=range(5)))

In [8]: cloud
Out[8]:
<xarray.DataArray (a: 2, b: 2, c: 5)>
array([[[0.32309854, 0.88812159, 0.08117742, 0.21431025, 0.83623298],
        [0.23355224, 0.44884835, 0.12812813, 0.0021359 , 0.49794295]],

       [[0.69559493, 0.37565047, 0.25932353, 0.88144778, 0.20781263],
        [0.45444069, 0.75168194, 0.32308855, 0.78148687, 0.34278779]]])
Coordinates:
  * c        (c) int64 0 1 2 3 4
Dimensions without coordinates: a, b
```

Taking a look at the first vertical slice, we can see that we have two "cloud" points, one at `c=1` and another at `c=4`. Note that the highest cloud fraction is at position 1 (0.888), but the highest elevation over 0.6 is at position 4. This is important.

```py
In [9]: cloud.isel(a=0, b=0)
Out[9]:
<xarray.DataArray (c: 5)>
array([0.32309854, 0.88812159, 0.08117742, 0.21431025, 0.83623298])
Coordinates:
  * c        (c) int64 0 1 2 3 4
```

By simply masking the locations where cloud fraction is > 0.6 and then finding the index of the max with `.idxmax`, we get the wrong answer, `id=1`, because this is the index of the maximum:

```py
In [10]: cloud.where(cloud > 0.6).isel(a=0, b=0)
Out[10]:
<xarray.DataArray (c: 5)>
array([       nan, 0.88812159,        nan,        nan, 0.83623298])
Coordinates:
  * c        (c) int64 0 1 2 3 4

In [11]: cloud.where(cloud > 0.6).isel(a=0, b=0).idxmax('c')
Out[11]:
<xarray.DataArray 'c' ()>
array(1.)
```

Instead, we can broadcast the elevation index `c` against the cloud mask to get an array of elevations where there are clouds:

```py
In [12]: cloud.c.where(cloud > 0.6).isel(a=0, b=0)
Out[12]:
<xarray.DataArray 'c' (c: 5)>
array([nan,  1., nan, nan,  4.])
Coordinates:
  * c        (c) int64 0 1 2 3 4

In [13]: cloud.c.where(cloud > 0.6).isel(a=0, b=0).max()
Out[13]:
<xarray.DataArray 'c' ()>
array(4.)
```

This gives us the correct elevation for this column. Applying this to the full dataset:

```py
In [14]: cloud.c.where(cloud > 0.6)
Out[14]:
<xarray.DataArray 'c' (c: 5, a: 2, b: 2)>
array([[[nan, nan],
        [ 0., nan]],

       [[ 1., nan],
        [nan,  1.]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan],
        [ 3.,  3.]],

       [[ 4., nan],
        [nan, nan]]])
Coordinates:
  * c        (c) int64 0 1 2 3 4
Dimensions without coordinates: a, b

In [15]: cloud.c.where(cloud > 0.6).max(dim='c')
Out[15]:
<xarray.DataArray 'c' (a: 2, b: 2)>
array([[ 4., nan],
       [ 3.,  3.]])
Dimensions without coordinates: a, b
```

You can then use this to select out the cloud fraction at these locations. Since not all locations have any clouds, you need to first fill NaNs with a dummy index value to select, then mask out the result:

```py
In [16]: max_cloud_elev = cloud.c.where(cloud > 0.6).max(dim="c")
    ...: dummy_elev = cloud.c.values[0]
    ...: cloud_frac_at_max_cloud_elev = (
    ...:     cloud
    ...:     .sel(c=max_cloud_elev.fillna(dummy_elev).astype(cloud.c.dtype))
    ...:     .where(max_cloud_elev.notnull())
    ...: )
    ...: cloud_frac_at_max_cloud_elev
Out[16]:
<xarray.DataArray (a: 2, b: 2)>
array([[0.83623298,        nan],
       [0.88144778, 0.78148687]])
Coordinates:
    c        (a, b) int64 4 0 3 3
Dimensions without coordinates: a, b
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, I tested it, and that's exactly what I wanted.